# Angular rxjs EffectsModule imports

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a parent and a child module with EffectsModule.forRoot and EffectsModule.forFeature imports. My parent module imports looks like this:

```
imports: [ 
    ...,
    ChildModule,
    EffectsModule.forRoot([ParentEffects]),
    ...
]
```

My child module imports looks like this:

```
imports: [ 
    ...,
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ChildEffects]),
    ...
]
```

Now for a component written in parent module to use ChildEffects, should I have to explicitly add ChildEffects to my EffectsModule.forRoot import or should the import of ChildModule in ParentModule take care of that? BTW, my exports array of ChildModule doesn't have EffectsModule.